# How to use Perl to increase CSS property value

Tags: css, regex, perl

I am supporting a site written by an external company, so although there are better ways to make CSS style definitions maintainable, I have the following definitions in multiple CSS files to fix:

```
.rect_frame {
   width: 980px;
   height: 2882px;
   padding: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.rect_headline1 {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

The ".rect_frame" class has a height set, but it varies depending on the page.  I need to add 65 to the pixel height for that class on each page to fix a footer.  To do so, I tried a bit of Perl regex, and the following script fails:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

-pi -e 's/(\.rect_frame\s{[.\r\s\w:;]*.height:\s)(\d*)/$1.$2+65/e' ./*.css;
```

I have checked the regex, so I suppose it is just not exactly how Perl needs it. Can you help find the syntax I need when running it as a Perl script?

Breaking down the regex:

```
(                -> start first set to grab
\.rect_frame\s{  -> grabs the initial class
[.\r\s\w:;]*     -> grab the rest of material from thereon
*.height:\s      -> stops grabbing after the height property and a space
)                -> end the first set to grab, used as $1
(\d*)            -> the digits to grab and add 65 to using the "/e" modifier, used as $2
```

And thereby the replacement:

```
$1.$2+65
```

Results:

```
Search pattern not terminated at ./fix_height_style.pl line 6.
```

This is specifically to solve the Perl issue.  Other languages and modules I welcome but I did want to solve this in Perl for my own learning.  My apologies if it is a simple syntax error.

Comment: `perl` is not a Perl command.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the error in copy/paste.

Comment: A non-greedy expression might simplify the problem:
s/(\.rect_frame\s+\{.*?\sheight:\s+)(\d+)/$1.($2+65)/e
or:
s/(\.rect_frame\s+\{[^}]*?\sheight:\s+)(\d+)/$1.($2+65)/e

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Usage:
#    script <in.css >out.css        Read from a STDIN
#    script in.css >out.css         Read from a file
#    perl -i script file(s).css     In-place without backup
#    perl -i~ script file(s).css    In-place with backup

use warnings;
use strict;

local $/;

while (<>) {
   s/.../.../eg;
}
```

The `local $/;` makes `<>` read the entire file instead of just one line at a time.

Comment: Good improvement, but now

    Argument ".rect_frame {\r\n    width: 980px;\r\n    height:2882" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ./fix_height_style.pl line 15, <> chunk 1.

Comment: The numeric warning is because of operator precedence. You want `$1.($2+65)` instead of `$1.$2+65`, which is treated like `($1.$2)+65`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I went with.  I acknowledge better string substitution solutions, memory savings, file handling from more experienced Perl programmers:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input;  # hold the lines to split
my $regex = '(\.rect_frame\s+\{[^}]*?\sheight:\s+)(\d+)';  # regular expression
my @css_array; # array of split lines

my @files = <*.css>; # get list of all CSS files in directory
foreach my $filename (@files) {
    open(INPUT_FILE, "$filename")
        or die "Cannot open file: $!.";
    while (<INPUT_FILE>) {
        $input = $input.$_;  # grab the lines
    }
    close(INPUT_FILE); # already have the lines, so close the file
    open(OUTPUT_FILE, ">$filename") # replace original CSS by opening as append
        or die "Cannot write to file: $!.";
    @css_array = split($regex,$input);  # split lines with regular expression
    print OUTPUT_FILE $css_array[1].($css_array[2]+65).$css_array[3];  # overwrite the file
    close(OUTPUT_FILE);
    $input = ''; # get ready for the next file's lines
}
```

Thanks to @mob, @kjpires and other comments.  Further help from:
www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html , alumnus.caltech.edu/~svhwan/prodScript/perlGettingInput.html , stackoverflow.com/a/2149386/3112527 , www.perl.com .